How to get the access_type "system"?
I failed to get the access_type "system" with many diff kinds of SQL, if you  can successfully get the access_type "system" with Explain SQL , please show me the SQL.

The pic above from doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/explain-output.html, for access_type "system" it say "The table has only one row (= system table). This is a special case of the const join type." , however I failed to figure out the table which has "only one row (= system table)", what's it? Who can figure out such table?
I tried to do the test below , none of them output the access_type "system":
Test 1)The  access type of the SQL below is "const" instead of "system".
CREATE TABLE single_row_table (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
value VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO single_row_table (id, value) VALUES (1, 'single_row');

EXPLAIN SELECT value FROM single_row_table WHERE id = 1;

Test 2)The  access type of the SQL below is "ALL"
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mysql.help_topic LIMIT 1;


I find just "Select * FROM mysql.proxies_priv;" can get the  access_type "system".

I guess you are using MySQL 5.x or else MariaDB, so that table is MyISAM. Correct?

@BillKarwin you are correct. for MySQL 8.0 that table is InnoDB， so it changes from system to ALL.

Effectively, you can't get access type system if you use an InnoDB table.
You get access type system only if the table access is not by a key.
I see this line of C code in the SQL optimizer. This is where it sets the access type for the EXPLAIN for a const or system access type.
tab->set_type(key ? JT_CONST : JT_SYSTEM);

The key referenced here is described in the comment:
  @param key    The key definition to use for this table (NULL if table scan)

But in InnoDB, the clustered index of a table is referred to as a key all over the place in InnoDB code. There is no access to an InnoDB table that is not by key.
I'm extrapolating, but I would infer that this key parameter is never NULL when the query is accessing an InnoDB table, even for a table-scan.
I can demonstrate using your example (I'm testing with MySQL 8.4.2 in my local environment):
CREATE TABLE single_row_table (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
value VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO single_row_table (id, value) VALUES (1, 'single_row');

EXPLAIN SELECT value FROM single_row_table WHERE id = 1;

+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | single_row_table | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+

But if I alter the table to MyISAM:
ALTER TABLE single_row_table ENGINE=MyISAM;

EXPLAIN SELECT value FROM single_row_table WHERE id = 1;

+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | single_row_table | NULL       | system | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+

A MyISAM table has no clustered index, so a table-scan is really row-by-row, i.e. not access by key.
I assume the same applies to other storage engines, but I didn't test them.
